# How do I use www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to consume this webservice...

http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx

When I add a web reference to this web service the methods it provides do not match what the asmx say.

I get methods like this....

```
ZipcodeLookup.GetInfoByZIPCompletedEventArgs
ZipcodeLookup.GetInfoByZIPCompletedEventHandler
```

And I have no idea how to use these. Am I doing something wrong when adding the reference or could someone possibly shed some light on to how I use these methods?

Thanks!

Comment: You won't only get methods, you'll get all the classes associated with the web service. Those two above look like event handler classes associated with functionality offered in the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a Web Reference is an older deprecated approach to WebServices (although it still works great).   For a service like this you need to add a Service Reference.  To do this, right click on refrences in your project and choose Add Service Reference.  Enter the URL in the address textbox and click "Go".  You then see a list of services available at the address you entered.  Choose "USZip" in this case and enter a namespace (ZipcodeLookup).

Your usage would now be

```
        var service = new ZipcodeLookup.USZipSoapClient();
        XmlNode result1 = service.GetInfoByAreaCode("410");
        XmlNode result2 = service.GetInfoByCity("Annapolis");
        XmlNode result3 = service.GetInfoByState("MD");
        XmlNode result4 = service.GetInfoByZIP("21401");
```

As @mattytommo says, you will get methods and the classes associated with the web service, meaning that if a web service returns a type of person you will get a DTO type class called Person.

Hope this helps.